# Calling PHP from console / command line not working

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to pipe the incoming mail to this script. So if I call "php /home/user/www/mysite/public/index.php -m" it works correctly. But if I call "/home/user/www/mysite/public/index.php -m" (without the php) I get HTML back I also added "#!/usr/bin/php" to the top of index.php and added "chmod +x index.php" but it's still returning HTML (default error page) if called without the leading php. Anyone know how to fix this?

Side note, why I need it to call without the php is because I used "default addresses" on my cpanel to pipe the incoming e-mails to this script. It just allows me to supply a script name. Not a prefix...

```
\#!/usr/bin/php
<?PHP
    .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, I just found the problem, it had nothing to do with Zend 2 at all.

I ran the command "which php" and it said:

## #!/usr/local/bin/php

NOT

## #!/usr/bin/php